# Is my Big O approximations correct?

Tags: big-o

I have an algorithm to determine if two strings are permutations of each other. The code can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/bxohcgjn/

```
N = String A
M = String B
For time complexity, i have: O(N(N logN + M logM))
For space complexity, I have: O(N + M)

N logN = for sorting A
M logM = for sorting B
```

I understand that the browser's implementation for sort will change it, but I am assuming quicksort.

Just want to see if my thinking is correct on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your time complexity, the `for` loop (the lineal order), must not be multiplied by the sum of both `sort`s.

If an algorithm consists of `n` steps, the order of the algorithm is the sum of their orders:

```
O(alg) = O(step_1) + O(step_2) + ... + O(step_n)
```

In your case, `n = 3` (both `sort`s and the `for`):

```
O(is_permutation) = O(sort_A) + O(sort_B) + O(for)
                  = O(n logn) + O(m logm) + O(n)
```

Which is the maximum of them:

```
O(is_permutation) = max(O(n logn), O(m logm), O(n))
```

But since you test before that the sizes of both strings must be the same before applying the `sort`, in the worst case (which is what you are analyzing), there is only one size, so, the expression is translated to:

```
O(is_permutation) = max(O(n logn), O(n logn), O(n))
                  = max(O(n logn), O(n))
                  = O(n logn)
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I realized I messed up on the O(n) for the `for` quickly but your steps/thought process is very helpful.

Comment: @MikeL I have changed the answer. Reed it again.